# Different Behavior for Different Syntax Errors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I'm not a JavaScript programmer so this might be a really basic question. The problem is when making some specific syntax errors the whole JS code wouldn't work.

Since JS is interpreted I thought it should execute each line independently until the error occurs, but it doesn't seem to happen, at least in the case below:

```
console.log('a')
consol.log('b')    //intentional typo in "console"
console.log('c')

---- output ----
a
ReferenceError: consol is not defined
```

The above example sounds all good based on how an interpreted language should work. Now take a look at the following error:

```
console.log('a')
console.log('b'    //intentionally didn't put the right parenthesis 
console.log('c')

---- output ----
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Why shouldn't the first line be executed?

N.B. I used https://playcode.io to run the code and did it on Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: The parser has to translate the entire code block before any of it can run. It does not parse line by line, in other words. The first error is not a *syntax* error because `consol.log('b')` is not *syntactically* incorrect.

Comment: Like @Pointy pointed out, another way of thinking about it if you have come from a compiled language, the first one is a runtime error, the second one is a compile error.

Comment: I'm no pro on this subject but guessing that these days modern browsers 'interpret' the javascript into another language (closer to the metal) before it's executed.  If it can't parse the script because of syntax errors, it can't interpret/parse the script into something else.

Comment: @phil the "closer to the metal" thing (I assume you mean JIT compiling) usually just happens if a certain code runs more often, but yes, the engine turns the code into an AST before running it..

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the comments. Absolutely got it now.

Comment: The only kind of code that _can_ be executed one "line" at a time is machine code. Any other kind of code, including assembler, has to be gobbled up in chunks ahead of time and interpreted. Once you realize that one difference between different languages is how big chunks and how many times times the chunks are processed. As it happens, _this_ JavaScript engine reads the entire file first in a "syntax" chunk, and then again in a "runtime" chunk. (And probably many more chunks, but those aren't apparent.)

Comment: @Odalrick AFAIK the ES spec (which all engines follow (more or less)) defines Early Errors which occur before the code gets executed.

Comment: @JonasWilms   Different JS engines might do things differently, but from what I can gather Chromes V8 is native code from the start, it's only CrankShaft (optimiser) that kicks in on code that run more often.

Comment: @JonasWilms Yes, pretty much all JavaScript engines work the same. I was thinking generally: if you enter those lines into a REPL the first line would get executed even with syntax errors on the second line. Similarly if it was two different script-tags in an html page, or different cells in runkit, or…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`consol` is not a ***syntax*** error, it's a *runtime* error.

Syntax is what defines the language, what makes the Javascript engine understand what you want it to do. `console.log('b' console.log('c')` is *invalid syntax*, since the Javascript engine can't tell whether you forgot some operator between `'b'` and `console` or whether these are separate statements or what it is you want.

However, `consol.log()` is a perfectly valid command, *assuming* some object named `consol` exists at runtime, which may or may not be the case at the point in time that line is supposed to be executed. You will only find out then.

Javascript always *parses and compiles* the entire code you give it to construct a runnable program. This is where *syntax errors* occur. Only when the syntax is correct for the entire code will it execute that code, which might or might not then produce *runtime errors*.

> Since JS is interpreted I thought it should execute each line independently

"Interpreted" has nothing to do with this. Take this:

```
while (foo) {
    bar();
}
```

Obviously it cannot execute each line independently here, since this is a compound construct. Or this:

```
foo();

function foo() {}
```

This `function` needs to be parsed and *hoisted* before `foo()` can be executed. No, code is always parsed from top to bottom *before runtime*.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is evaluated in two phases. In the first phase, the interpreter turns the whole code into an abstract syntax tree and collects all variables in environment records and so on. In that stage Early Errors occur, that means that the parser is unable to understand your code. The second phase is when the code gets actually run, and then runtime errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't it be possible that the compiler thinks the 3rd line is still an argument of the line above since you didn't close the parenthesis correctly?

For example,

```
console.log('a')
console.log('b',
console.log('c'))
```

would be valid code.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you could have defined a function `consol.log()`. You haven't, but it's still able to be parsed as a function call.

In the second, the browser cannot parse it. An enclosed `(` is syntactically incorrect.

In short, what matters is where in the parser the error is found.

[image]