# Why does JavaScript go on to print a syntax error instead of printing an earlier type error in my terminal?

Tags: javascript

```js
//declare and assign
const firstName = 'bangalore'
console.log(firstName)

//reassign
firstName = 'mysore'
console.log(firstName)//type error

//redeclare
const firstName = 'chennai'
console.log(firstName)//syntax error
```

If JavaScript is an interpreted language because it executes code line by line and stops executing when it encounters an error, then why in my case is the type error not printed in my terminal? Instead, it skips and goes on to print syntax error?

Comment: You have defined `firstName` as a constant. Change `const` to `let`.

Comment: The console breaks on the line `firstName = 'mysore'` so not sure what you are talking about. Not sure what the errors you are talking about exactly. The error should be `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'firstName' has already been declared",`

Comment: @epascarello It breaks on the line `const firstName = 'chennai'`. I think OP's is asking why it doesn't break on `firstName = 'mysore'` instead.

Comment: Duplicate of [Different Behavior for Different Syntax Errors in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51787909/different-behavior-for-different-syntax-errors-in-javascript) - unfortunately the close banner won't display that because the first two CVers misunderstood the question and thought this was a case of a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Redeclaring is considered a *syntax* error, which happens as soon as the engine tries to parse the JS code. The TypeError is raised at runtime, which happens *after* parsing.

Answer (score -3):

because you set firstName variable as const (from constant - means invariable value) and later try to reassign it. use let instead of const for this specific case

Comment: OP asks why the SyntaxError appears _before_ the TypError, not why an error appears at all.